# Shell scripts for the database logs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

The actual log file will be like this

```
$ cat file1.log
time=2014-07-23 23:56:28 GMT, user=[unknown], db=[unknown], host= pid=28254 LOG: 
time=2014-07-23 23:56:28 GMT, user=portalman, db=ss, host=172.18.183.45 pid=28254 LOG:  connection authorized: user=portalman database=ss
time=2014-07-23 23:57:28 GMT, user=[unknown], db=[unknown], host= pid=28269 LOG:  connection received: host=172.18.183.45 port=14493
time=2014-07-23 23:57:28 GMT, user=portalman, db=ss, host=172.18.183.45 pid=28269 LOG:  connection authorized: user=portalman database=ss
time=2014-07-23 23:57:28 GMT, user=[unknown], db=[unknown], host= pid=28270 LOG:  connection received: host=172.18.183.45 port=14494
time=2014-07-23 23:57:28 GMT, user=portalman, db=ss, host=172.18.183.45 pid=28270 LOG:  connection authorized: user=portalman database=ss
time=2014-07-23 23:57:58 GMT, user=[unknown], db=[unknown], host= pid=28273 LOG:  connection received: host=172.18.183.45 port=14495                                            
column "actice" does not exist at character 17
.
.
.
```

The total lines will be around 20,000. In this log file I need to fetch the unique errors, which I got through this command:

```
$ find file1.log | xargs grep -e ERROR -e FATAL | cut -d ":" -f4,5 |sort |uniq
```

Following is the result set and it not constant, it varies

```
syntax error at or near "?" at character 1
syntax error at or near "[" at character 1
syntax error at or near "desc" at character 1
syntax error at or near "describtion" at character 1
```

For getting the process id (pid) of each error I used:

```
$ find file1.log | xargs grep 'syntax error at or near "?" at character 1' | cut -d " " -f8 | tail -1
pid=25997
```

Now I got the process id,then I need to fetch the entire information of that process id

```
$ find file1.log  | xargs grep pid=25997
time=2014-07-23 23:10:02 GMT, user=[unknown], db=[unknown], host= pid=25997 LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
time=2014-07-23 23:10:02 GMT, user=dbman, db=ss, host=[local] pid=25997 LOG:  connection authorized: user=dbman database=ss
time=2014-07-23 23:10:02 GMT, user=dbman, db=ss, host=[local] pid=25997 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?" at character 1
time=2014-07-23 23:10:02 GMT, user=dbman, db=ss, host=[local] pid=25997 STATEMENT:  ?column?
```

How to put all the 3 find commands in a shell script & do the process automatically? The errors & number of lines varies. Nothing is constant.

Comment: First of all, `find filename | ..` is wrong!  Secondly, you can use `grep -iE '(pid=25997|ERROR|FATAL)' filename`  to group everything in one command.  So can you explain why you are using find in this case?